# How to pass variables in TS files in NGX Translate

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

as we know ,in HTML file, we can use pipe to pass variable like this , so that different language can turn into inversion,
how can I make it in ts file.

`<div class="condition">{{ 'canUseTreshold' | translate: { restrictionAmount: item.threshold } }}</div>`

here is my ts code:
`${this.translate.instant('full')}${item.thresholdStr}${this.translate.instant('deliveryFeeDiscount')}${idx !== discountList.length - 1 ? '、' : ''};`

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if I understood correctly, but do you want to pass variables for translation in ts?

If you check the documentation of how the instant method works, you will notice that the second parameter is an object where you can pass your variables.

[ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#methods)

> instant(key: string|Array, interpolateParams?: Object):
> string|Object: Gets the instant translated value of a key (or an array
> of keys). /!\ This method is synchronous and the default file loader
> is asynchronous. You are responsible for knowing when your
> translations have been loaded and it is safe to use this method. If
> you are not sure then you should use the get method instead.

```
this.translate.instant('full', { restrictionAmount: item.threshold })
```

Comment: that's what I want, I figured this out,and checked the doc,and now it works well

Answer (score 2):

You want to pass params to translation files like so:

Where `item.threshold = 123`

```html
<div class="condition">{{ 'canUseTreshold' | translate: { restrictionAmount: item.threshold } }}</div>
```

JSON i18 file

```json
"canUseTreshold": "text text text {{restrictionAmount}} text text"
```

Result:

```
text text text 123 text text
```

Comment: The single space before the two last curly brackets is important. If left out it generates a compile error.